# Request["key"] Correspondent in Asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am trying to integrate Mercado Pago API (https://www.mercadopago.com.br/developers/pt/guides/payments/web-tokenize-checkout/receiving-payment-by-card/) into my ASP.NET Core Application. However, I am not an equivalent way to get the parameters that Mercado Pago send me...

Their SDK for .Net framework gives the following example:

```
token = Request["token"]
payment_method_id = Request["payment_method_id"]
installments = Request["installments"]
issuer_id = Request["issuer_id"]
```

Any ideas of how to get same result in ASP.Net core?

Comment: See following page : https://www.mercadopago.com.br/developers/pt/plugins_sdks/sdks/official/dotnet/

Comment: I think this code I will need to run after having, at least, the token. I am one step behind

Comment: Your code is showing how to get data.  My code is showing how to store data.  If you look at my link there are two static methods 1)find_by_id() 2)search()  You can use either of these two methods to get the token.  The request is really using the static method(s).

Comment: Can you capture the request from `Mercado Pago`? For [HttpRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest?view=netframework-4.7.2) , `Request["key"]` retrive value from  QueryString, Form, Cookies, or ServerVariables collections, you could try to check the properteis by `Request.QueryString`, `Request.Form`, `Request.Cookies`, check the `Request` object for details in .net core.